# Get range from one row to another in a loop

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, row-number

I have a problem writing a script which gets a range from one row to another row and does it in a loop.
I have a sheet with rows of data and rows of headers above each batch of data. 
I need to loop through a range on that sheet and gather data into arrays.

This is how it looks like, and what I need to do:

```
row 1 - header
row 2 - data
row 3 - header
row 4 - data
row 5 - data
row 6 - data
```

Array1 should be row 1 and row 2, array2 should be row 3,4,5 and 6, and so on. I should have around 15 arrays on this sheet. The data constantly changes, so as the row numbers and the number of data rows under each header.

```
  var sourceID = "source spreadsheet ID";
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
  var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName("ANALYSIS REPORT"); // the sheet the data is on

  var SWrowss = findCellForSW(); // start row - calling from another function, this will ALWAYS be the start row of range
  var CQrowss = sourcesheet.getLastRow(); // last row
  var noRows = CQrowss - SWrowss; // gets number of rows in range
  var colss = sourcesheet.getRange(SWrowss,6,noRows,1).getValues(); // range of column the headers are in - headers are in column F, data starts in column E

  var arrayS = getArrays(sourceID); // calling function to get variables
  var rowNumbers = arrayS[1]; // row number of data (row 2,4,5,6 in example)
  var rowNames = arrayS[0]; // string for header names (row 1 and 3 in example)
  var nameRowN = arrayS[2]; // row number of headers (row 1 and 3 in example)
  var colssR = sourcesheet.getRange(SWrowss,6,noRows,1); // range of the column headers are in
  var firstRow = colssR.getRow()
  var numRows = colssR.getNumRows(); // gets number of rows in array

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) { // gets the correct row numbers
    var absoluteRow = firstRow + i;
  }
```

So at the moment I have the row number for pretty much everything, but can't write a working loop to get the necessary data.

Comment: Can you please share a sanitised copy of your sheet?

Comment: Great! Would it be possible to share a copy of your script too, as it has been omitted from the copy and so I can't see how functions like `findCellForSW()` work.

Comment: Sorry, I should've made it this way at the beginning. I shared my full code as well!